# Bind water animation to keyframe

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I'm currently making a bar scene.
One of the guests is holding a keg upside down, I made the water animation for it.
But I want to make the camera go through the stream of pouring beer at frame 180.

*How do I delay the animation so it starts at frame 179, so the camera can catch the initial pouring?*

[image: Animation already happened at 179]

Comment: You can adjust the offset with the "Offset" paremeter above the "Bake" button on your picture.

Comment: Is that "Offset" value where you put the starting frame number? because I typed in 179 at "offset" but now the animation is almost completed at frame 1

Comment: Offset adjusts the simulation start forwards (if set negative) or backwards (if set positive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that works for this:

Make sure you have saved the .blend file, and have baked your fluid simulation completely. (This isn't *required* but is optimal.)

Once ready, set the offset amount. Negative (one for each frame ahead) postpones the simulation one frame. Positive makes the simulation a frame earlier.

Here are some pictures:

[image]

Offset -15 frame one:

[image]

Frame 15 offset -15:

[image]

Hope this helps!