# Fluid starting point

Tags: fluid-simulation

I want to run a fluid simulation, but I want the fluid to start at some other frame than the start.

How do I make the simulation start on a farther frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by adjusting the *offset* value of the fluid simulation.

Here's a short summary of this:

Go to the offset settings of the Blender fluid domain (Assuming you are using Blender v2.81 or before), and adjust the value to a higher number to make the simulation happen earlier, and lower to happen later.

This will cause your fluid to show up later or earlier depending on the offset *value*. For a detailed answer to a similar question, look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165798/bind-water-animation-to-keyframe/165833#165833).

Comment: AWESOME THANKS!